# Accordion has a default active panel, but it won't open

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am using a frontend library called Element UI to create some accordions on my website. I got an array of objects that I like to create accordions for. FYI, from the element ui website: the `v-model` used on the accordion specifies the `currently active panel`. The `name` attribute is the unique identification of the panel. That means I can do:

```
<el-collapse v-model="activeName" accordion>
  <el-collapse-item title="Consistency" name="1">
    <div>content content content</div>
  </el-collapse-item>
  <el-collapse-item title="Consistency" name="2">
    <div>more content more content more content</div>
  </el-collapse-item>
</el-collapse>
```

One this loads, the first accordion will open since in the data object, `activeName` is set to `1`:

```
data() {
    return {
      activeName: '1',
    }
}
```

Now I thought I'd just loop through the array and create accordions for the items in my array, and binding the `name` attribute to the `index + 1`, so that the first item will have the `name` attribute equal to `1`, the second to `2` etc. So:

```
<el-collapse v-model="activeName" accordion>
            <el-collapse-item
              v-for="(item, index) in experience"
              :title="item.company"
              :name="index + 1"
              :key="index"
            >
              <div> content content content </div>
            </el-collapse-item>
</el-collapse>
```

But for some reason, when the page loads, the first item in the accordion won't open automatically. They're all closed by default. I created a codesandbox with the problem that you can see for yourself here:  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-no5eg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run a for loop and assign `name`, it's a number and not a string.

```
:name="index+1"    <---- This is a number
```

But, `activeName` is a string. So, the values don't match and that's why the accordian does not open on page load.

Here's an updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ysm79

I changed `activeName` to a number. The for loop accordian will now open and the normal HTML accordians won't.

Comment: That makes sense... I didn't think that would be a problem since the `name` attribute expects a `string` or a `number`. But of course it can only be one of the two and not a `string` AND a `number`. Thanks a lot for your answer!